# Defining derivatives of integrals

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to define a derivative of a function which is itself an integral.  The function `GaussInt[f_,x_]` is the integral over f (a function of x) with respect to the measure $\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$.  I prefer to use the function `GaussInt` rather than write out the integral to prevent mathematica from attempting to solve the integral (which it can't do, but it spends a lot of time trying).  The problem is that `GaussInt` doesn't satisfy the usual chain rule.  That is

```
D[GaussInt[f_,x_], z_]:= GaussInt[D[f,z], z]
```

but Mathematica uses the chain rule to decide

```
D[GaussInt[f_,x_], z_] := GaussInt'[f,x] D[f,z]
```

which usually leads to the wrong answer.

I can get around this by defining my own differentiation operator

```
Dd[GaussInt[a_,z_],x_] := GaussInt[Dd[a,x], z]
```

I then have to define all the usual rules for `Dd`.  Although this works its is rather inelegant.  My problem is I don't know how to robustly switch off the chain rule for differentiation when applied to my function `GaussInt`
.  Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the input and output when you ask for the derivative of `GaussInt`?  Are you doing `D[GaussInt[f,x],x]`?  Because this evaluates to `Derivative[0, 1][GaussInt][f, x]` (which displays as $\mathrm{GaussInt}^{(0,1)}[f,x]$), not `GaussInt'[f,x]` (the latter doesn't make sense, as prime is only used for a single-variable function).

Comment: Note that it would be better for you to post the actual input or output rather than putting them in a `:=` form (unless, of course, your input was in the form of a `:=` statement).

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) :

```
Inactive[Integrate][f[x] Exp[-x^2/2]/Sqrt[2 π], x]
```

which leaves the integral unevaluated (and formats the output as an integral).  Then it plays nicely with derivatives:

```
D[%, x]
```

[image: Evaluation screenshot]